# Despotify, node-spotify-web and Spotify track id representation

Tags: node.js, spotify, despotify

I'm using [node-spotify-web](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-spotify-web),
I guess the protocol is the same as Despotify, at least it seems that booth of them uses 16 bytes to represent a Spotify track id (32 hex chars).

That's what I get in the xml response when I search for a track.

My problem is that a [Spotifiy track id](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/documentation/) is supposed to be a 22 chars 0-9a-zA-Z string.

I don't know how to convert this to the actual track id and i was unable to find it in any of the two project's documentations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A conversion functions is in the project!

It can be found [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-spotify-web/blob/master/lib/util.js)!